# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for pyipinfo

Tags: python

I am trying to use `pyipinfo`, a python tool to get the IP location from a list of IPs in a `.txt` file. I use the following command

`$ cat iptest.txt | ipinfo >iptest_location1.csv`

which shows the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipinfo", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipinfo/__init__.py", line 45, in main
    text += u'{}\t'.format(info[k])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3 installed.

code of the File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipinfo/**init**.py" :

```
from __future__ import print_function

from __future__ import absolute_import

import sys

import requests

from ipinfo.utils import ip_list_from_string

from ipinfo.utils import is_piped


def request_to_ipinfo(ip):

    ''' return a json from the request '''

    full_url = 'http://ipinfo.io/{}'.format(ip)

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl/7.30.0'}

    req = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers)

    if req.status_code == 200:

        return req.json()


def main():

    if is_piped():
        input_string = sys.stdin.read()
        ip_list = ip_list_from_string(input_string)
    else:
        ip_list = ['']

    if ip_list == []:
        exit()

    ip_set = set(ip_list)

    ips_info = []
    for ip in ip_set:
        ips_info.append(request_to_ipinfo(ip))

    all_keys = [
        'ip', 'city', 'region', 'country',
        'hostname', 'org', 'postal', 'loc'
    ]

    for info in ips_info:
        text = ''
        for k in all_keys:
            try:
                text += u'{}\t'.format(info[k])
            except KeyError:
                text += '\t'
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `request_to_ipinfo` function, you return req.json() if the `req.status_code` is 200:

```
if req.status_code == 200:
        return req.json()
```

What do you return if the `req.status_code` is not 200?

You don't have an explicit return statement, so the function returns `None`, and you append that to `ips_info`:

```
for ip in ip_set:
    ips_info.append(request_to_ipinfo(ip))
```

Then, at some point, you try to get `info[k]` from that `None` object (which is not a dict, but a `NoneType`), and of course you get `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

So that's your problem. The correct solution depends on what you want to do if you don't get a `200` response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `ipinfo.utils` in the project because the functions was in an other file so here is the full code I write it by Python 3.X

```
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
import requests
import re
import os
import stat


def ip_list_from_string(string):
    return re.findall(r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+', string)


def is_piped():
    '''
        script is called from a pipe
        echo ip | ipinfo
    '''
    mode = os.fstat(0).st_mode
    return stat.S_ISFIFO(mode)

def request_to_ipinfo(ip):

    ''' return a json from the request '''

    full_url = 'http://ipinfo.io/{}'.format(ip)

    headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl/7.30.0'}

    req = requests.get(full_url, headers=headers)

    if req.status_code == 200:

        return req.json()


def main():

    if is_piped():
        input_string = sys.stdin.read()
        ip_list = ip_list_from_string(input_string)
    else:
        ip_list = ['']

    if ip_list == []:
        exit()

    ip_set = set(ip_list)

    ips_info = []
    for ip in ip_set:
        ips_info.append(request_to_ipinfo(ip))

    all_keys = [
        'ip', 'city', 'region', 'country',
        'hostname', 'org', 'postal', 'loc'
    ]

    for info in ips_info:
        text = ''
        for k in all_keys:
            try:
                text += u'{}\t'.format(info[k])
            except KeyError:
                text += '\t'
        print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```